# Marie] Вычислить арифметическое выражение

Tags: ассемблер

Как реализовать вычисление выражения `r=15(x+y-z)` в симуляторе [Marie](https://marie.js.org/).

Как умножить на 15?

```
Input
Store x
Input
Store y
Input
Store z
Load x
Add y
Subt z
Store r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как операции умножения нет, то ее нужно реализовать сложением в цикле:

```
loop,    Load result
         Add r            / на каждом шаге добавляем (x+y-z)
         Store result     / тут накапливаем результат умножения

         Load M           / счетчик цикла
         Subt one
         Store M
    
         Skipcond 400     / достигло ли M нуля
         Jump loop        / если нет, переходим на loop
```

Предполагаем, что у нас объявлены переменные

```
one, DEC 1
M, DEC 15
r, DEC 0
result, DEC 0
```